# The right way to check if an html element exist

Tags: javascript, html, dom

What is the proper way to check if an html element exist in a webpage.

I do like this:

```
    if (document.getElementById('container') !== null) {doThis()}
```

How good is this?
What are other ways?

Comment: Well that is not checking an element.... that is checking if getElementById is defined.... I assume you meant to do `if (document.getElementById("id") !== null)` That is basically on of the ways to find the element exists or not.... Any way you do it, you need to reference the element....

Comment: Ye, i forgot the parenthesis..(fixed)

Comment: The answer is, that is basically how you do it.... You can doa truthy check, but it is basically the same thing...

Comment: it should work directly work with - `if (document.getElementById('id'))`

Comment: That is good to, but I just curious if there are other ways?

Answer (score 0):

**Answered**

I was looking for

```
document.body.contains(element))
```

Comment: So guessing your question is not exactly what you were asking if this is your answer....

Comment: I just wanted to find another way.

Comment: But that code is still requiring you to look up the element which if you used getElementById would be still null.... so you would be doing `contains(null)` which is not any better than `if(elem)`. Now how it would work with contains if you had an element reference that was not added to the DOM yet and than would not be added. `var div = document.createElement("div"); console.log(document.body.contains(div));`